# fatal error Index out of range in tabelview

Tags: swift, uitableview

I want to navigate from tableview to different `ViewController` here is the code i have written I want the values of which are stored in my model class in different view controllers where ever I need them Here is the code I have written it is giving me

> fatal error: Index out of range

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) 

    switch(indexPath.row)
    {
        case 0 : let v1 = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "pass1") as! ViewControllerngodetails
        v1.t = arrayNGO[indexPath.row]

        navigationController?.pushViewController(v1, animated: true)
        break;

        case 1 : let v2 = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "pass2") as! ViewController2Reg
        v2.e = arrayNGO[indexPath.row]
        navigationController?.pushViewController(v2, animated: true)

        break;
        case 2 : let v3 = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "pass3") as! ViewController3FCRA
        v3.t = arrayNGO[indexPath.row]

        navigationController?.pushViewController(v3, animated: true)

        break;
        case 3 : let v4 = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "pass4") as! ViewControllersectorkeys
        v4.t = arrayNGO[indexPath.row]

        navigationController?.pushViewController(v4, animated: true)

        case 4 : let v5 = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "pass5") as! ViewController5contactdet
        v5.t = arrayNGO[indexPath.row]

        navigationController?.pushViewController(v5, animated: true)

        case 5 : let v6 = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "pass6") as! ViewController6bnkdetails
        v6.t = arrayNGO[indexPath.row]

        navigationController?.pushViewController(v6, animated: true)
        default: break
    }
```

Comment: `arrayNGO` is shorter then `indexPath.row`

Comment: Means how do i solve it

Comment: Whats `arrayNGO.count` gives you? & how many `numberOfRows` in your `tableview`

Comment: It stores all the json values that I need to pass it in different view controllers so I m passing whole array every time i m navigating in swiftch case

Comment: for case 0 in switch it is running fine but when i navigate back to tabel view it gives error for case 1:

Comment: Check your datasource items count

Answer (score 0):

Try to Print arrayNGO.count on certain line to know the exact value of your Array

add this line before switch statement to know your code.

```
print(arrayNGO.count)
```

Comment: it gives 1 for case 0 and at case 1 it crashes and gives error Index out of range as we back navigate

Comment: I think the problem is in view will appear code here what should i write to call my json function in view will appear